# Why is this program yielding wrong output

Tags: c

This program is supposed to remove all comments from a C source code (in this case comments are considered double slashes '//' and a newline character '\n' and anything in between them, and also anything between '/* ' and '*/'.

The program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* This is a multi line comment
testing */

int main() {
int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == '/') //Possible comment
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == '/') // Single line comment
            while (c = getchar()) //While there is a character and is not EOF
                if (c == '\n') //If a space character is found, end of comment reached, end loop
                    break; 


        else if (c == '*') //Multi line comment 
        {
            while (c = getchar()) //While there is a character and it is not EOF
            {   
                if (c == '*' && getchar() == '/') //If c equals '*' and the next character equals '/', end of comment reached, end loop
                    break;
            }                   
        }

        else putchar('/'); putchar(c); //If not comment, print '/' and the character next to it
    }

    else putchar(c); //if not comment, print character
}

}
```

After I use this source code as its own input, this is the output I get:

```
#include <stdio.h>

* This is a multi line comment
testing *

int main() {
int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    if (c == '') ////////////////
    {
        c = getchar();
        if (c == '') ////////////////////
            while (c = getchar()) /////////////////////////////////////////
                if (c == '\n') ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    break; 


        else if (c == '*') ///////////////////
        {
            while (c = getchar()) ////////////////////////////////////////////
            {
```

No more beyond this point. I'm compiling it using g++ on the ubuntu terminal.

As you can see, multi lines comments had only their '/' characters removed, while single line ones, had all their characters replaced by '/'. Apart from that, any '/' characters that were NOT the beginning of a new comment were also removed, as in the line if (c == ''),  which was supposed to be if (c == '/').

Does anybody know why? thanks.

Comment: Putting curly braces around every logical block fixed it "magically" for me. I didn't bother to find the *exact* error, but consider the line `else putchar('/'); putchar(c);` -- it most certainly will not do what you think. Also, consider what happens if you start with `printf("This program will strip //comments\n");`.

Comment: You'll either need a recursive-descent program (like yours) or a finite state machine with relevant symbols { EOF , '/' , '*' , '\n' , and maybe '\' and '\'' and '"'} and approximately 10..20 states.

Comment: @wildplasser. I don't know much about finite state machines, but it seems that it would indeed work better in this case, because as someone else pointed out, I could have something like printf("This is not // a comment\n");   in my input, and then I suppose I could use a "InsideString" state. thanks!

Comment: Creating an FSM by hand can be a good exercise. If you start by leaving out the "" and '' strings (they change the meaning of '\n' for instance) you can succeed with very few states (approx 5, I guess). Then add the string logic and the thing will explode to maybe 20 states. Still maneagable, and very illustrative. Another way would be to use (f)lex for building the DFA (but lex parsers often have hard-coded stuff to deal with comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C does not take notice of the way you indent your code. It only cares about its own grammar.

Look carefully at your `else`s and think about which `if` they attach to (hint: the closest open one).

There are other bugs, as well. `EOF` is not 0, so only the first `while` is correct. And what happens if the comment looks like this: `/*  something  **/`?

Comment: I added some curly braces and the comments were removed correctly. It seems that c++ behaves differently than c when it comes to code indentation, or am I wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: @LucasMezalira: you're wrong :) indentation is between you and your editor, unless you're writing in python.

Comment: @LucasMezalira Indentation should not matter in either language (though I'm no expert on C++), the problem is rather that the `else` that you thought belonged to the `if` outside the loop, actually belonged to the one inside it. But that was not obvious due to your indentation. Hint: extra curly braces almost never hurt!

Answer (score 1):

## You have some (apparent) logic errors...

### 1.

```
while (c = getchar()) //While there is a character and is not EOF
```

You're assuming that `EOF == 0`.  Why not be explicit and change the preceding line to:

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

### 2.

```
else putchar('/'); putchar(c);
```

Are both of the `putchar`s supposed to be part of the `else` clause?  If so, you need braces `{}` around the two `putchar` statements.  Also, give each `putchar` its own line; it not only looks nicer but it's more readable.

### Conclusion

Other than what I've mentioned, your logic looks sound.

Comment: Note that `if (c == '')` is part of the *output*, not the actual code (where it corresponds to the line `if(c == '\n')`).

Comment: @Kninnug Ah yes! Fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the if/else matching is incorrect. One aditional missing functionality is that you must make it more stateful to keep track of whether you are inside a string or not, e.g.

```
printf("This is not // a comment\n");
```